# Can I use urlfetch with self signed certifications over ssl

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https, self-signed

I want my app engine service to speak with a separate service that I manage. I want to be able to install my self signed certificate on both ends. Is it possible to have app engine speak to this instance over SSL?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you know how to do what you want by using urllib2, you can still use these classes in AppEngine.  urllib2 seems to be a wrapper to urlfetch.

Comment: @dplouffe As you say, urllib(2) is a wrapper for urlfetch, so you can't do anything with it that you can't do with urlfetch.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. App Engine doesn't currently verify certificates for SSL sites over urlfetch, so it will accept self-signed certificates just fine.

Comment: I see, but can you upload your self signed certificate? If you cannot do this, I believe an attacker could spook as your external server. If the attacker can somehow reroute your request to their own server, they will trust whatever ssl certificate you throw at them. So you aren't ever really sure if you are speaking to your external service which should be serving you over ssl?

Comment: @1337Rooster No, you can't verify the certificate of the remote machine. You're correct that URLFetch, as it stands, does not provide MitM protection for SSL connections.