# App Engine URLfetch to validate self-signed certificate

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use [URL Fetch API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) to make Https requests to my backend service.

I'm using HttpsURLConnection because my backend is using a self-signed certificate and I need to validate that certificate as trusted.

This snippet

```
...
URL url = new URL("https://example.com/api");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

throws

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

I know that App Engine employs its own handler for `url.openConnection()` which returns a sibling to `HttpsURLConenction`, which is why the cast fails.

Is there a way for me to use HttpsURLConnection with URLfetch? Are there other options to connect to my backend via Https?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866754/dropbox-java-api-with-gwt-authentication-problems this looks similar to me.

Comment: You can enable / disable certificate validation in the urlfetch low level api (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/FetchOptions). That won't work for self signed certificates though... Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939701/can-i-use-urlfetch-with-self-signed-certifications-over-ssl

Comment: Thanks for the links. Seems like `HttpsURLConnection` is simply unsupported... I thought it would be possible because appengine white lists HttpsURLConnection. I guess I'll have to get a CA for my backend then